# How to add curve modifier to text?

Tags: modifiers

I am relatively new to blender and am trying to wrap some text around a hair spray bottle that I made.  I have watched many tutorials on how to do it, but it never seems to work.  I am trying to wrap my text around the cylindrical part of the bottle with the curve modifier, but am running into troubles.  When I select the bottle with the selection within the curve modifier, I get a "failed to set value" message at the top of my screen.  And then, when I try to apply it, I get the message "modifier is disabled, skipping applied."  Does any one know if there is a setting that I need to change to enable this curve modifier?

Here is a screen shot of my project if it helps:
[image]

Comment: it's not an answer to your question, but in more complex cases you could look into the shrinkwrap modifier as well. Happy Blending

Answer (score 5):

This can also be done with no curves.
Create a lattice object that is as big as the text but that is only one segment deep. Place the lattice at the back of the text

[image]

On the text object add a lattice modifier and select the lattice as Object:

[image]

Select the lattice and add a shrinkwrap modifier and choose the cylinder as target.

The lattice will wrap around the cylinder and the text will be deformed by the lattice.

[image]
You might want to refine the placement on around the surface with the Offset value.

Answer (score 3):

To use the ***curve modifer*** you need to have a **curve object**.

[image]

To create one place the 3d cursor in the same place as your text's origin and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to Add->Curve>Bezier Curve.

Select the text and on the curve modifier set the bezier courve as the object to control the distortion for the text.

[image]

Editing the curve will allow you to distort and place the text.

[image]

Comment: When I select my object, I get a "failed to set value message," and how do I get the thing to curve the text in the gif?

Comment: @NicholasJacobs [Shift]+[A] > *curves* > *Bezier curve*.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Curve Circle [Shift]+[A] > Curve > Circle  and set it to the same center point and radius as your bottle.  Then apply the curve modifier with a -X Deformation Axis.  Finally, change the Text Object's X rotation to bring it up to a vertical orientation.

Keep in mind, with both this and the Bezier curve approach above, each character will be warped around the circle, causing deformities on the face of the text.  To achieve a smooth curve across the face of the text, you'll need to do something similar to what's described in this post:

https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?366006-How-to-curve-SVG-text-object-for-3D-printing

If you wish to avoid the face distortion, it will be necessary to place each character on the curve manually, avoiding the curve deformation altogether.