# How can I wrap a mesh around another?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, transforms

I want to wrap the barbed wire around the heart. Similar to the shrinkwrap modifier, but while keeping the volume of the mesh. Is there anyway this is possible?

[image]

Comment: have you tried curve deform?

Comment: @m.ardito I'm very new to this program, if there's any steps you can give me to follow i would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There are already many question with answers detailing this, eg: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33434/how-to-add-curve-modifier-to-text (although is about a text object). Try to search for similar threads, and if something is not particularly clear, ask referring to them.