# How to wrap text on top of an object

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, modifiers

I have a pencil here I modeled and I want to wrap some text around it. I have been trying this method: [What's the simplest way to wrap extruded text around a cylinder?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6226/whats-the-simplest-way-to-wrap-extruded-text-around-a-cylinder) but this is not working for my pencil. I am trying to wrap the text on top of the object. here is what i am trying to achieve:

[image]

As you can see, the letters H and B are wrapped around the pencil. Here is my scene:

[image]

Please help. is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Can you show some detail on why _"it's not working"_  For example the curve you are trying to wrap around? Are the pencils round or hex in cross section?

Comment: Instead of a mesh try using a texture to avoid Z-fighting. If you must do a mesh see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/emboss-text-onto-curved-surface/44820#44820. and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33434/how-to-add-curve-modifier-to-text/60958#60958

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52904/wrap-curve-around-sphere/52905#52905

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion you don't need to bend a mesh to do this. Just use a texture and use the geometry of your object. Avoid overlapping geometry and prevent z-fighting. If you use the texture as a bump map or as a displacement map you can control the indentation or relief (and will help you keep a low vetex count).

[image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447

Comment: @cegatron thanks a ton it worked. never thought of using a texture/ you saved me thousands of vertices.