# How to slap faces onto an object?

Tags: modeling

I'd like to apply, or slap faces onto an object, how do I do that? I can't remember what was the function (or plugin?) I know it's a basic tool for topology..

[image]

Comment: What you're looking for is a shrinkwrap modifier.

Comment: Shrinkwrap! That's it! Thank you.. is it part of Blender, or is that an add-on?

Comment: It's a part of blender - it's in the modifiers tab

Comment: cool, thank you very much!

Comment: But why do you want to do that? Having faves that are touching or very close will cause problems with z-fighting. Do you want to do that to add a texture? If so it is easier to add the texture as part of the material. Please exlplain what your goal is.

Comment: umm to have faces slapped on, or wrapped around an object

Comment: You want to subdivide your plane at least as much as your receiving geometry here or else it will clip inside it. Also consider this method https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/98784/86891 as suggested in the comments