# Morphing an object around another object

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to add an Aquila to the chest plate of a space marine I'm modelling. Is there a quick way to morph an object around another object as per the picture I attached?

[image: What I'm trying to do]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33434/how-to-add-curve-modifier-to-text/60958#60958

Comment: @cegaton Thank you!