# Curve text around cylinder

Tags: bezier-curves, text-object

I'm new to Blender so please excuse this question. I know there is already a [question regarding this topic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6226/whats-the-simplest-way-to-wrap-extruded-text-around-a-cylinder), however I'm having trouble with the solution posted there.

I want wo wrap text around a cylinder, but it should not be flat but "stand" on the curve, like this:
[image]

To do so, I created a bezier circle and used the "Text on curve" option to make the text follow the circle. Now it looks like this:
[image]

In the answer to the question I posted above, it says I should rotate the text on the x-axis to achieve the "standing" effect. However when I rotate it on the x-axis, it looks like this:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

P.S. Please excuse my english, I'm not a native speaker! :)

Comment: I think that you are trying to use the Font text on curve option, but the solution you reference on the other page uses a Curve Modifier on the text object to make it follow the curve, and then you can rotate on axis until you get the position correctly.

Comment: Oh, there is a difference between "Font text on curve" and "Cruve modifier"? I thought it was the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33434/how-to-add-curve-modifier-to-text/60958#60958 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/emboss-text-onto-curved-surface/44820#44820

Answer (score 0):

Add a text and convert it to mesh. Add an empty and use Simple Deform modifier > Bend with the empty as origin and high, like 4, Deform factor. You may want, too,remesh and subdivide the text mesh.

[image]