# Wrap an object with thickness and curvature around another object

Tags: modeling, modifiers, shrinkwrap, lattice, surface-deform

I'm trying to wrap this strap structure around my model's leg:

[image: ![enter image description here]

It already has a thickness, so simple Shrinkwrap doesn't work. I've found some tutorials using a lattice with Shrinkwrap, then Surface Deform by the Shrinkwrapped lattice:

[image]
(from [How to add curve modifier to text?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33434/how-to-add-curve-modifier-to-text/60958#60958))

But the object is flat. I don't know how to build the lattice for my curved strap, or whether it's even the right approach. What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: I'm not following.  do you want your strap object to exactly match the limb, so the strap's inside surfaces just touch the limb's surfaces?

Comment: @MartyFouts Yes! Thanks for making it clearer. I couldn't come up with a better description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could duplicate the inner faces of your strap, separate as a new object (*Strap2*):

[image]

Give your strap a *Surface Deform* with *Strap2* as *Target*. Give *Strap2* a *Shrinkwrap* modifier with your leg as *Target*, tweak the *Offset* value a bit:

[image]

Comment: sometimes i wonder if they are questions you couldn't answer.... :D